# android - End View blinks Material Container Transition

Tags: android, android-transitions

I have an activity which shows a BottomSheetDialog through BotomSheetDialog b = new BottomSheetDialog();. When clicking on a view inside this dialog there is supposed to be a container transition between the view and a new activity which is shown as a dialog(im using theme Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.Dialog to make it into a dialog). It works properly but at the end of the animation the dialog activity blinks once before finishing the animation and in the logs the message

```
 E/RippleDrawable: The RippleDrawable.STYLE_PATTERNED animation is not supported for a non-hardware accelerated Canvas. Skipping animation.
E/FrameEvents: updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
```

shows(i tried enabling hardwareaccelerated).

I tried:
-Enabling transitiongroup on the views(Relativelayout and cardview which both contain childs).
-using a fade animtion and setting excludetarget on the views.

Code:
MainActivity(initial one with bottomsheeetdialog)

```
public class QuickPanelMain extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        config();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quick_panel_main);
        MaterialButton show = findViewById(R.id.show);
        show.setOnClickListener(v -> showMainDialog());

    }

    private void config() {
        setExitSharedElementCallback(new MaterialContainerTransformSharedElementCallback());
        getWindow().setSharedElementsUseOverlay(false);
    }

    private void showMainDialog() {
        BottomSheetDialog dialogZ = new BottomSheetDialog(this);
        dialogZ.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_quick_panel);
        dialogZ.setCancelable(true);
        CardView sectionOne = dialogZ.findViewById(R.id.sectionOne);
        RelativeLayout parentX = findViewById(R.id.parentX);
        sectionOne.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Intent intentZ = new Intent(this, SensorInformationActivity.class);
            Bundle transitionData = ActivityOptions
                    .makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this, sectionOne, sectionOne.getTransitionName()).toBundle();
            startActivity(intentZ, transitionData);
        });
        dialogZ.show();
    }
}
```

CardView inside the bottomsheetdialog

```
    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/sectionOne"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginVertical="10dp"
        android:transitionName="sensorinfo"
        android:transitionGroup="true"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="#1AFFFFFF"
        app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
        app:cardElevation="0dp">
```

The Dialog Activity(which blinks)

```
public class SensorInformationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        config();
        setTheme(R.style.Dialog_Grey);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sensor_info);

    }

    private void config() {
        RelativeLayout dialogY = findViewById(R.id.dialogY);

        setEnterSharedElementCallback(new MaterialContainerTransformSharedElementCallback());
        MaterialContainerTransform transform = new MaterialContainerTransform();
        transform.setEndView(dialogY);
        transform.addTarget(R.id.dialogY);
        transform.setDuration(500);
        getWindow().setSharedElementEnterTransition(transform);
        getWindow().setSharedElementReturnTransition(transform);
    }
}
```

The dialog activities layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@null"
    tools:context=".quickpanel.SensorInformationActivity"
    android:id="@+id/parentY">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/dialogY"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/background_blue"
        android:transitionName="sensorinfo"
        android:transitionGroup="true">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/sensor_info"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/header"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="20dp"
            android:layout_marginVertical="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/section_white">

        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The Theme im using

```
    <style name="Dialog.Grey" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.Dialog">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/grey</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/grey</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white_dim</item>

        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/blue</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/blue</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/white_dim</item>

        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/grey</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">?attr/colorOnPrimary</item>

        <item name="background">@null</item>
        <item name="android:animateLayoutChanges">true</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/leaguespartanfont</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowActivityTransitions">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowSharedElementsUseOverlay">false</item>
    </style>
```

I want this animtion to work the same as the quicksettings tile for wifi in android 13.
[Thats what happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vI6t6.gif)

I think its a problem with me using a drawable as background for the dialog.